# CakePHP 2.x: Custom Logging

Tags: cakephp, logging

I've got a CakePHP application that receives instant payment notifications from PayPal. I'd like to log the data that gets posted by PayPal. I could easily do that using something like this:

```
file_put_contents(LOGS . 'ipns.log', date('Y-m-d H:i:s ') . print_r($_POST, true) . "\n", FILE_APPEND|LOCK_EX);
```

But I prefer to do things "the CakePHP way™" whenever possible. I've already looked through [the "Core Libraries > Logging" section of CakePHP's cookbook](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/logging.html) and am having trouble understanding it. I know it's *not* correct to do this:

```
CakeLog::write('ipns', print_r($_POST, true));
```

Although the above does seem to work, it can also cause problems, as shown [here](http://cakephp.lighthouseapp.com/projects/42648-cakephp/tickets/3100-cakelog-writes-twice).

So what is the CakePHP way to do this? Or should I just use the raw PHP shown at the top of this question?

Comment: I supposed that is the Cake way. It is just buggy. Use this, knowing the issues it can cause, or use pure PHP, which is probably what cake is using underneath.

Comment: It is not. The cake way would be to use a custom logger.

Answer (score 4):

What you want is explained here http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/logging.html#creating-and-configuring-log-streams

But I would suggest you to read the whole page and not just this section.

I would write the ipn to a database table field by field and not into a file log. I can tell you this based on my experience with the paypal API. The advantages are obviously, you can for example lookup the ipns for an order, search for errors and so on.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm still having trouble understanding the cookbook. Also, there's another instance that I'd like to implement logging. I have a form that was occasionally being filled out by bots, so I added some fake fields and hid them with CSS. I'd like to log whenever a bot is detected, like this: `if ($this->request->data['Model']['fake_field'] != '') {CakeLog::write('bot_log', 'Bot from ' . CakeRequest::clientIp() . ': ' . print_r($this->request->data, true));}`. I want it to be in "bot_log.log" and not "debug.log" or anything else. Would you mind providing a code sample?

Answer (score 3):

According to [Writing to log](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/logging.html#writing-to-logs) paragraph of *Logging* section of the 2.x cookbook:

> `CakeLog` **does not auto-configure itself anymore**. As a result log files
>   will not be auto-created anymore if no stream is listening. Make sure
>   you got at least one `default` stream set up, if you want to listen to
>   all types and levels. Usually, you can just set the core `FileLog` class
>   to output into `app/tmp/logs/`:
>
> ```
> CakeLog::config('default', array(
>     'engine' => 'File'
> ));
> ```

So, in order to make `CakeLog::write('ipns', print_r($_POST, true));` to write to custom file `app/tmp/logs/ipns.log` you need in `app/Config/bootstrap.php` instead of:

```
/**
 * Configures default file logging options
 */
App::uses('CakeLog', 'Log');
CakeLog::config('debug', array(
    'engine' => 'File',
    'types' => array('notice', 'info', 'debug'),
    'file' => 'debug',
));
CakeLog::config('error', array(
    'engine' => 'File',
    'types' => array('warning', 'error', 'critical', 'alert', 'emergency'),
    'file' => 'error',
));
```

write:

```
/**
 * Configures default file logging options
 */
App::uses('CakeLog', 'Log');
CakeLog::config('default', array(
    'engine' => 'File'
));
```